# Asm cmp go to the comparing address?

Tags: assembly, x86

Hey I am new to assembly and I try to add a compare to game memory.
Since I didn't get it working someone gave me this aob code:

```
cmp [esi+15],02841362
```

It is working fine but I would like to see with which address it compares with (02841362).
So there are Modules like UserAssembly.dll just static adresses like 22FAA2512 but If I Go to the address 02841362 there are only ?????????????? instead of actual opcode.

So is the 02841362 even an address and if so how can I go to it?
If not what else could it be, a float?

Comment: No, that's not an address. That is just a value. The address is `esi+15`. (Technically the `02841362` could also be an address but this instruction does not use it to access memory.)

Comment: If you want to see more what's going on when you're in the debugger, then use smaller instructions with fewer addressing modes, and more registers.  For example, `mov eax,02841362h`; `mov ebx,[esi+15]`; `cmp eax,ebx`; should do the same thing as the `cmp` you have, but will let you inspect `eax`, and `ebx` in the debugger to see what values are being or will be compared.

Comment: (Of course, that would step on the previous values of EAX and EBX, so you can't just drop that in to most functions.)